# Vertical coordinate of specific line in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am making an UML tool (http://www.nomnoml.com) where you enter code that is translated into a diagram.

When the parsing fails it should display a marker at the failing line of code.

I need to find the vertical pixel coordinate of line X within this textarea. Hard coding the pixel height of a line does not behave consistently across different browsers :(

How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by harcoding the pixel height? If you define in your style the line height of the text area, it should be the same in all browsers, no?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it thanks to Djizeus.

Problem was that I used the `font-size` for the height of a line. Specifying `line-height` solved it.